# MongoDb Date conversion

Tags: mongodb, date, date-conversion

I have a large query running on a collection pulling back the date in NumberLong format, I then export to a .csv where I run a formula to convert the date to a format a human can use. Scrolling the web I am not able to find a clear way of pulling the date in 'YYY-MM-DD' format and not the NumberLong on the fly. Has anyone managed this?

Comment: Hi Thomas, welcome to Stackoverflow! Questions need to have a [clear problem statement](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you provide a code sample, someone may be able to help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this as a once off action, one way of doing this is to use the [forEach()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach) method to convert the date and inject the new converted object into a temporary collection. Then dump that collection to CSV.

Something like this:

```
db.myCollection.find().forEach(function(element) {
    element.dateField = new Date(element.dateField);
    db.myTempCollection.insert(element);
});
```

Otherwise, I recommend using your programming language of choice and implementing a program or script to do the conversion.